# Regarding Lightning Communities

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, community, slds

We are looking at an implementation where the client wants us to build salesforce communities for clients(customer communities). Client wants us to support IE9 and higher for browsers.

from SLDS FAQ its very clear they dont support IE9 and napili communities support starts from IE11

One of the options we are looking at is using Visualforce with lightning components with bootstrap. but Lightning out has its limitations.

The approach we have in mind is visualforce communities with bootstrap and frontend Libraries like Angular or Jquery.

I wanted to check with experts here if this is the right thing to do.

Comment: Don't offer support for browsers Salesforce itself does not support. That's just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

None of the Napoli Templates will support IE9. Salesforce in general has already ended support for IE9 with VisualForce. Although it will still work, official support for IE11 has also ended for security reasons.

Salesforce recommends that all customers upgrade to Windows 10 and Microsoft Edge Browsers if they wish to continue using Microsoft Browsers instead of Chrome or Firefox. This is something you should advise your customer of.

The only alternative to support older browsers will be to create custom pages and forgo using any of the templates. For more, see [KB 000233325](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Retirement-of-Support-for-Microsoft-Internet-Explorer-version-11-with-Lightning-Experience&type=1).